# Expectations in Infinite Probability Spaces with Sub Sigma-Algebras

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ be an (integrable) random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Suppose $\mathcal{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$ and let $Z=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$.

(a) Show that: $\mathbb{E}(X-Z)=0$

(b) Let $Y$ be an arbitrary $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable. Show that: $\mathbb{E}[(X-Z)(Z-Y)|\mathcal{G}]=0$

(c) Show that: $\mathbb{E}[(X-Z)(Z-Y)]=0$

(d) Suppose that $\mathbb{E}(X-Y)=0$. Show that: Var$(X-Z)\le$ Var$(X-Y)$.

Hint: Break up $X-Y = (X-Z)+(Z-Y)$.

The ideas that need to be proven all make sense to me intuitively, but I just don't know how to go about formalizing the actual proof itself in an infinite probability space. I tried approaching it from a finite probability space standpoint, but I don't think it's working.

Answer (score 2):

you are asking four questions at the same time.
I will try to answer the first and maybe you can take it from there.

First of all we have to understand the definition of the conditional expectation give a sigma-field $Z=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$.
$Z$ is a random variable which satisfies three properties (by definition):

1. $Z$ is integrable, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(|Z|) < \infty$.
2. $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.
3. $\mathbb{E}(Z \cdot 1_G ) = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1_G )$ for all $G \in \mathcal G$. This is the most important property.

All of your questions can be solved using this definition.

For your first question we take property 3 and set $G = \Omega$. Then we get that
$$
\mathbb{E}(Z) = \mathbb{E}(Z \cdot 1_\Omega )  = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1_\Omega ) = \mathbb{E}(X).
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
0 = \mathbb{E}(X - Z) = \mathbb{E}(X) - \mathbb{E}(Z).
$$

Hope this helps a little.

### Edit (part b)

In order to prove (b) you have to show that the random variable $W = 0$ has all three defining properties of $\mathbb{E}((X-Z)(Z-Y)|\mathcal{G})$. The first two are trivial to show.
For the third property you have to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}((X-Z)(Y-Z) 1_G) = \mathbb E(W 1_G) = 0, \quad \text{for all} \ G \in \mathcal{G}. $$

This can be done by a classical procedure:  first you assume that $Y = 1_A$, then you assume that $Y$ is a simple function, than we assume that $Y$ is a positive random variable (monotone convergence), and finally we can show it for general $Y$.

Comment: Thank you! In moving to part b - I know that (Z-Y) is G-measurable, and I have the result from part a - but how do I move to actually doing the proof for the conditional expectation?

Comment: I edited the answer to give you a idea about b

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for so many follow-ups, but I think I was able to do part (b) - would you be able to provide a hint as to how to generalize my answer from (b) to part (c) without the conditional part of the expectation?

Comment: simply take $G = \Omega$ in (b)

Comment: Sorry - reiterating back to (b), can I not just say that $\int_A (X-Z)(Z-Y)d\mathbb{P} = \int_A (XZ-ZZ-XY+YZ)d\mathbb{P} = \int_A (XX-XX-XY+YX)d\mathbb{P}$ from the property of $Z$ and conclude that $\int_A (XX-XX-XY+YX)d\mathbb{P} = 0$? Why do we have to go through the whole process with each of the 4 possibilities?

Comment: No, because the property holds only for $\int_A Z$ and not for $\int_A ZZ$

Comment: Can I use the 'taking out what is known' property to do that?